# Remove existing object

Tags: object

I have written some code like this.

```
    public void Preview()
    {            
        _printTemplate = new MarineBunkerPrintTemplate();           
        UpdateInfo();
        _printTemplate.SetInfo();
    }
```

Here whenever i call `Preview()` method i am creating new object of `_printTemplate`, Instead of i have to check existing object available or not avilable means i have to delete existing and i have to create new and use or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context in which it is used, but how about:

```
public void Preview() 
{   
   if (_printTemplate == null)
   {   
        _printTemplate = new MarineBunkerPrintTemplate();            
   }
    UpdateInfo(); 
    _printTemplate.SetInfo(); 
}
```